# mongodb oplog: does "insert" op add "create collection" op?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-oplog

When we insert a document, if the database and/or collection do not exist, they are create before the insert. Is this "create db/collection" operation available in the oplog?

The reason I'm interested, is because we want to upgrade from v2.4 to v3.2 but according to https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17634, the "applyOps" command will fail on insert ops if the collection is missing.

Comment: You will need to upgrade 2.4 to 2.6, then 2.6 to 3.0, then 3.0 to 3.2. It is quite a long chain. If I were you I'd made such upgrade only within a maintenance window without any writes to the db. In this case there is no need to replay opplog.

Comment: We replay the oplog because we keep mirrors with our clients' data. So whenever the send us data, we have to replay the oplog. However, I don't understand why the update has to be gradual

Comment: Please read https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.2-upgrade/index.html regarding upgrades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, inserting to a new collection makes 2 entries in the oplog:

1. `{op: "c", o: {create: "name_of_the_collection"}}` to create the collection
2. `{op: "i", ns: "name_of_the_collection", o:{the document}}` to insert the document

**Answering the follow up questions:**

The [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) reads:

> The oplog (operations log) is a special capped collection that keeps a rolling record of **all operations** that modify the data stored in your databases.

"all operations" include create collection, database etc. If collection does not exists on primary member, it's created on first insert: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v3.2/src/mongo/db/catalog/database.cpp#L454

When new collection created, the corresponding document recorded to the oplog: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v3.2/src/mongo/db/catalog/database.cpp#L511

Same logic apply to other commands, including create database.

[Format of oplog documents](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v3.2/src/mongo/db/repl/oplog.cpp#L364) contains all necessary information to replay all operations on correct database, collection, and document:

```
/* we write to local.oplog.rs:
     { ts : ..., h: ..., v: ..., op: ..., etc }
   ts: an OpTime timestamp
   h: hash
   v: version
   op:
    "i" insert
    "u" update
    "d" delete
    "c" db cmd
    "db" declares presence of a database (ns is set to the db name + '.')
    "n" no op
   bb param:
     if not null, specifies a boolean to pass along to the other side as b: param.
     used for "justOne" or "upsert" flags on 'd', 'u'
*/
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any official documentation stating this? I couldn't find anything before posting the question

Comment: What about the "create db" op? How does `applyOps` know to which db this collection belongs to?

Comment: I guess it's the same as the `ns`? In the form of `db.collection`?

Comment: I have updated the answer, but it drifted from the original question. It is recommended to create separate questions, rather than extend existing ones.

Comment: So basically there is no documentation stating that 2 entries are added in oplog if collection/db doesn't exist. I don't think that the edit to your answer replies any of my follow up questions. It was just a minor confusion of what the `name_of_the_collection` you have in your answer refers to

Comment: I don't think so. If you check the links in the answer, the logic to create a collection on first insert belongs to database, not replication. For oplog these are 2 different operations, and it does not distinct between implicit or explicit creation of a collection.